# AngularJS - mask/hide XHR network events from debugger

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Would like to check if is there such a way that I can prevent javascript events from logging into the debugger like image below?

[image: events]

I realized that I can actually see the response data from server in debugger. How should I hide it such that it will not be printed out in the debugger?

Comment: I don't think you can, but anyway what is the reason to hide it?

Comment: @richardtz well i was just thinking if you see under the "Preview" section, and if you expand those arrows you can actually see the information inside. Since some of the information are not suppose to be visible to the user on screen (info to be processed by javascript and display the final result to user) but they can find it by using such an approach...

Comment: then it will need to be processed on the server side, and return only the data the user will be allowed to see. Even if you could hide it from the debugger, there are lots of other ways to capture the traffic and inspect it. (A malicious user will probably use them)

Comment: I think you can use JSONP and they won't show up in the console

Comment: @Neil, using JSONP will apear under the script tab instead of the XHR one.

Comment: Most people think this as a security flaw, but the response is already being used to   manipulate the page items where the user would see it eventually. So there is no point in hiding the response, although it can be masked. Strangely enough, we don't see such traditional responses when logging into facebook or other giant networks.